# JTAG cable and device interchangeability

Tags: jtag

I see a lot of device specific JTAG cables such as AVR jtag or specific ARM JTAG.  Is there any such thing as a 'standard' JTAG cable that will work on multiple devices? I want something that will work with xilinx FPGAs, STM32s and AVR microcontrollers

Comment: They are also asking about a standard pin-out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the "JTAG" cables for different families of devices are not compatible. However as Leon notes, there are some 3rd party companies that produce "JTAG" cables that can be reconfigured to support different families of devices.

Comment: Just a side note.  The hardware portion of JTAG is the same for all devices, it's the actual instructions that differ between manufacturer's.  One can make a JTAG cable fairly easily, it's just 4 wires that you can assert slowly, so bit banging works.  The tricky part is in getting these instruction sets.  A lot of manufacturers don't want to tell you their instruction sets.

Answer (score 6):

[Amontec](http://www.amontec.com/chameleon.shtml) makes a reconfigurable JTAG. I've got one, and have used it with ARM chips and Xilinx FPGAs and CPLDs.

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to match your tool.  [This site](http://www.jtagtest.com/pinouts/) lists quite a few (doesn't have any references, so double-checking is an absolute must before you lay it out)

For AVRs, [their recommended pinout](http://www.jtagtest.com/pinouts/avr) matches what the [AVR JTAGICE mkII](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2562.pdf) uses (see page 3).

Answer (score 2):

The signals are defined (although some of them are optional), but the connector and pinout are not. [Here](http://www.etoolsmiths.com/blog/jtag-connector-pinouts/) are some examples. A 20-pin connector seems to be fairly universal for ARM JTAG.

Comment: Is there a "most common" layout? I'm using an AVR32 processor.

Comment: I'd use what is used by Atmel on their AVR32 boards.